# Assigning values to elements in an array in C (Beginner question)

Tags: arrays, c, loops

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = get_int("input number: ");
    int array[8];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ((n / 2) != 0)
        {
            array[counter] = n % 2;
        }
        else if ((n / 2) == 0)
        {
            array[counter] = 0;
        }
        counter++;
        n = n / 2;
        printf("%i ", array[counter]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Hi everyone,
What I am trying to do with this code is to get an array of binary numbers for inputted decimal number.
The problem I am currently seeing is that an array is being updated with some random numbers. First iteration of the loop is OK but iteration (counter = 1) gives a random number to an array (checked with a debugger).

Tried inputting `4` but I received back random numbers for `array[1]`, `array[2]` etc (I am guessing something from memory elsewhere?

Any ideas what could be causing this?
Thank you!

Comment: I think your conditions `if ((n / 2) != 0)` and `else if ((n / 2) == 0)` should be using `%` instead of `/`, and the test in the `else` is redundant, and indeed the assignment `array[counter] = n % 2;` could be used in place of the 8 lines of then entire `if`/`else` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `printf("%i ", array[counter]);` accesses the array element that has not yet been set because you incremented `count` before this `printf` statement.
- the test `if (n / 2 == 0)` seems inappropriate because what you are really interested in is the remainder of the division: use `n % 2` instead.
- there is no need for the test as you can simply write:

  ```
      array[counter] = n % 2;
  ```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = get_int("input number: ");
    int array[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        array[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `printf("%i ", array[counter]);` after `counter++`. It will not print the array element you assigned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below corrected code for reference :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)

{
    int n = get_int("input number: ");
    int array[8];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if ((n % 2) != 0)
        {
            array[counter] = n % 2;
        }
        else if ((n % 2) == 0)
        {
            array[counter] = 0;
        }
        printf("%i ", array[counter]);
        counter++;
        n = n / 2;
        
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```